# Change the regression line colour of Seaborn's pairplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to change the color of the regression lines to a different one. I found a similar question regarding a joint plot, however, as far as I know it is not analogical to the pairplot. I am attaching an example:

```
import seaborn as sns; 
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris, kind="reg")
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to pass `plot_kws` as a dict. You can change the regression line with `line_kws`. Refer to [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) for more information.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris, kind="reg", plot_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'red'}})
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution is already very nice. Just for sake of completeness to the answer I would suggest to create a "corner" plot by not showing the axes to the upper (off-diagonal) triangle of the grid. You can do that by adding the `corner=True` parameter.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris, kind="reg", corner=True, plot_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'red'}})

# A different color for each group
# g = sns.pairplot(iris, kind="reg", hue="species", corner=True, plot_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'red'}}, diag_kind="hist", palette="husl")

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Output with different colours:
[image]

Comment: In the grouped version of this (hue="species"), can I choose a different color for each regression line per group?